# How long is a MySQL table locked when selecting data from php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, locking

I am currently playing around with MySQL and PHP, and I was wondering about table locks. From the MySQL documentation I know that MySQL applies table wide read locks, which can cause other queries to wait until the select query finishes.

When I am using PHP to query data like in this example:

```
$dbConnection = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass) 
mysql_select_db($dbName, $dbConnection) 

$qry = "select * from bigTable";
$result = mysql_query($qry, $dbConnection);

//Read Data

mysql_close($dbConnection);
```

When, from the perspective of the PHP code, will the read lock get removed from "bigTable"?

Thank you,
Emi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lock is released at the end of your read query:

```
$result = mysql_query($qry, $dbConnection);
```

because you are doing per-query transactions.

If you want to do more complex transactions, make sure that you use the innodb engine and start your transaction:

```
mysql_query("START TRANSACTION", $dbConnection)
mysql_query("BEGIN", $dbConnection);
```

Then do your work:

- for example read a table
- then write some values, etc.

and either commit or rollback the transaction:

```
mysql_query("COMMIT", $dbConnection);
mysql_query("ROLLBACK", $dbConnection);
```

depending if you want the changes to go through or not.

Comment: Does this mean the lock is released as soon as the mysql_query method returns?

Comment: Yes, this is a single transaction. If you want to do more complex transactions (and therefore lock the table during the duration of the transaction), you would need to use InnoDB and start a transaction (see my edited answer)

Comment: Thank you. 

Does this also apply if the result set is very large (or even to large to fit in PHP's memory?)

Comment: Yes, same principle applies. That being said, it is always difficult to know what happens when memory problem occurs. I would suggest that you to load data in batches instead of loading in one shot.

Answer (score 0):

it is locked untill all you selected is read, depending on the table engine the lock ranged from whole table to row entry.

Check innoDB it is on rowlock-level